# Calling man of command works, calling command does not

Tags: bash

When using man for the rename command the manual is pulled up. However, when trying to actually use the command the terminal states that the command is not installed. I have check the path variable and it looks ok.My version is xubuntu 20.04. I have not removed perl or changed the default shell. I am using a desktop.

Thanks

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  Have you made changes to default shell (ie. replaced `bash` with something else?)  If you `whereis rename` does it show, likewise following that path does end up at the end perl script (without your release details, you maybe different.. so adjust per your release)  You haven't removed Perl or anything have you?

Comment: The output of `update-alternatives --query rename` might be helpful here

Comment: whereis rename outputs `/usr/bin/rename.ul /usr/share/man/man2/rename.2.gz` this is in my $PATH at least /usr/bin

Comment: update-alternatives --query rename outputs `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for rename`

Comment: The manual page you are seeing in section 2 (`man2`) is that of a low-level C function - it doesn't relate to the standalone `rename` *command* (in any of its variants `file-rename`, `rename.ul` etc.)

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  (desktop, server, appliance, etc)

Comment: I get the same. Ubuntu server 20.04.1. On my Ubuntu 16.04.6 server rename works fine, although the man page looks different. Hours ago, I up-voted the question, but someone seems to have down-voted it since. The man page is man1. I think it is a good and worthy question.

Comment: My version is xubuntu 20.04. I have not removed perl or changed the default shell.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the details you posted in your comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657) @DougSmythies I find the downvote (not mine) reasoned as the question is lacking details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is actually `rename.ul` and the man page you are seeing is as supplied by the util-linux package.

The key indicators are: `man rename` is the same as `man rename.ul`, unless you have the perl version of rename installed (which is the one most of us are familiar with), then `man rename` is different;  This line from the bottom of the man page:

```
util-linux June 2011 RENAME(1)
```

Then if you lookup the package contents of util-linux you see rename.ul, but not rename. And yes, this is confusing.